# History.API - как при вводе URL в адресную строку перевести приложение в определённое состояние?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

```
history.pushState(null, null, "/admin/add_post");
```

С помощью "pushState" меняю URL при переводе приложения в определенное состояние. Теперь при вводе в адресную домен/admin/add_post, браузер говорит о том, что запращиваемый ресурс не найден.

Пытался перехватить входящий URL с помощью кода:

```
window.addEventListener("popstate", function(e) {
    url = location.href;
    uri = url.slice((url.indexOf("old/admin/") + 10));
    show_condition_on_URI();
});

function show_condition_on_URI(){
    if(uri == "add_post"){
        /* тут динамический вызов определенного состояния */
    }
}
```

Использую jQuery + Ajax.

Comment: Добрый вечер. При вводе нового адреса в браузерную строку, браузер делает запрос к вашему сервису по указанному url, вам нужно на стороне сервера обработать этот запрос и отрисовать нужную страницу. Ловить это изменение на клиенте "костыль", который не спасёт от того, что я захочу открыть эту страницу в другом браузере и поделиться ей с другом

Comment: Здравствуйте, Павел, спасибо! Попробую сделать, как вы сказали =).

Answer (score 1):

Используя модуль mod_rewrite веб-сервера Apache сделать редирект из субдиректорий в корневую, где размещено ваше одностраничное приложение. Как это сделать описано [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8617830/7388307). Как получить предыдущую url написано [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3528331/7388307).